# Not able to return std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> from function

Tags: c++, function, vector, data-structures, tuples

I'm trying to write a function which returns `std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>`. I successfully created two `std::vector<int>` start_offsets_vector and end_offsets_vector. And initialized the tuple as below:

```
std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> A::createTuple(
    std::string paragraph) {
  ...

  std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> offsets_tuple =
    std::make_tuple(start_offsets_vector, end_offsets_vector);
  return offsets_tuple;
}
```

Some debugging information here:
[image]

But when the function returns, an exception happened at `return offsets_tuple` when it returns. Callstacks are listed below:
[image]

Is there any step wrong regarding having a function that returns a tuple that contains two vectors? I would really appreciate your perspective, thanks a lot!

Comment: The exception happens because of a bug somewhere else in your program. There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Just because your C++ program crashes here doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in the code that executed until this point, except that the program didn't immediately crash but continued until the memory corruption caused by the bug finally resulted in a crash here.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on exception and debug it again, seems your constructor throws.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: Requests for debugging help *must* include a [mre]. Your code does not define `A` (maybe `A::` could be removed from the function name?) and invoking it with the argument of my choice failed to reproduce the error. *(The MRE does not need to be functional in the sense of your overall program, but it must have enough code to reproduce the error. You could start with what you have and try adding code until the problem re-appears. Maybe see if you can get rid of the parameter to keep the example simpler.)*